# Mirror team foundation server 2015 git repo to bitbucket

Tags: git, team-foundation-server, mirror

I have a tfs 2015 server with a git repo. When a developer carries out a sync, I would like tfs to also push the changes to bitbucket git repo.

Can anyone suggest any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box with TFS 2015 you get Server Hooks. These can be configured to call a service when and event, like check-in, is triggered.

If you create a script that does the push, then rub it when the hook is triggered then you should be good.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/explore/explore-vso-vsi.aspx

Although the link is for VSO to os relevant for tfs as well..